# NetworkingError (EPIPE) while uploading big files into S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, multipartform-data

I am trying to uploading a large size video file into an S3 bucket. It works when I am uploading an Image (small size files), but I am getting the following error when I uploaded large video files into an S3 bucket. (NetworkingError)

**Error Message:**

```
    Upload part error: { Error: write EPIPE
      at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:868:14)
    message: 'write EPIPE',
    errno: 'EPIPE',
    code: 'NetworkingError',
    syscall: 'write',
    region: 'us-east-2',
    hostname: 'bucket-name.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
    retryable: true,
    time: 2018-12-12T20:23:37.883Z,
    statusCode: 400 }
    Retrying upload of part: # 12
    /Users/arunkumar/Documents/React/test/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
              throw err;
              ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'ETag' of null
      at Response.<anonymous> (/Users/arunkumar/Documents/React/test/src/s3uploadServer.js:97:21)
```

**Server.js**

```
        var express = require('express')
        var app = express()
        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        var fs = require('fs');
        var zlib = require('zlib'); // gzip compression
        const cors = require('cors');
        app.use(cors());
        app.options('*', cors());
        var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty'),
            multipartyMiddleware = multiparty();

        var AWS_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx';
        var AWS_SECRET_KEY = 'yyy';
        AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY});
        AWS.config.region = 'us-east-2';

        app.use("/public",express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        app.use("/node_modules",express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));

        // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

        // parse application/json
        app.use(bodyParser.json())

        app.post('/test-upload', multipartyMiddleware, function (req, res) {
            console.log("request ", req.files.file)
        var s3 = new AWS.S3();

        var file = req.files.file;
        var buffer = fs.readFileSync(file.path);

        var startTime = new Date();
        var partNum = 0;
        var partSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5; // 5mb chunks except last part
        var numPartsLeft = Math.ceil(buffer.length / partSize);
        var maxUploadTries = 3;

        var multipartParams = {
            Bucket: 'bucket-name',
            Key: file.name,
            ContentType: file.type
        };

        var multipartMap = {
            Parts: []
        };

        console.log('Creating multipart upload for:', file.name);
        s3.createMultipartUpload(multipartParams, function(mpErr, multipart) {
            if (mpErr) return console.error('Error!', mpErr);
            console.log('Got upload ID', multipart.UploadId);

            for (var start = 0; start < buffer.length; start += partSize) {
            partNum++;
            var end = Math.min(start + partSize, buffer.length);
            var partParams = {
                Body: buffer.slice(start, end),
                Bucket: multipartParams.Bucket,
                Key: multipartParams.Key,
                PartNumber: String(partNum),
                UploadId: multipart.UploadId
            };

            console.log('Uploading part: #', partParams.PartNumber, ', Start:', start);
            uploadPart(s3, multipart, partParams);
            }
        });

        function completeMultipartUpload(s3, doneParams) {
            s3.completeMultipartUpload(doneParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) return console.error('An error occurred while completing multipart upload');
            var delta = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
            console.log('Completed upload in', delta, 'seconds');
            console.log('Final upload data:', data);
            });
        }

        function uploadPart(s3, multipart, partParams, tryNum) {
            var tryNum = tryNum || 1;
            s3.uploadPart(partParams, function(multiErr, mData) {
            console.log('started');
            if (multiErr) {
                console.log('Upload part error:', multiErr);

                if (tryNum < maxUploadTries) {
                console.log('Retrying upload of part: #', partParams.PartNumber);
                uploadPart(s3, multipart, partParams, tryNum + 1);
                } else {
                console.log('Failed uploading part: #', partParams.PartNumber);
                }
                // return;
            }

            multipartMap.Parts[this.request.params.PartNumber - 1] = {
                ETag: mData.ETag,
                PartNumber: Number(this.request.params.PartNumber)
            };
            console.log('Completed part', this.request.params.PartNumber);
            console.log('mData', mData);
            if (--numPartsLeft > 0) return; // complete only when all parts uploaded

            var doneParams = {
                Bucket: multipartParams.Bucket,
                Key: multipartParams.Key,
                MultipartUpload: multipartMap,
                UploadId: multipart.UploadId
            };

            console.log('Completing upload...');
            completeMultipartUpload(s3, doneParams);
            }).on('httpUploadProgress', function(progress) {  console.log(Math.round(progress.loaded/progress.total*100)+ '% done') });
        }

        var server = app.listen(9000, function () {

        var host = server.address().address
        var port = server.address().port

        console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
        })
```

Please share your answers to solve this error. And It will save my day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any solution about this situation?